# Image & Text Positioning

Tags: html, css, image, position, themes

How would you have the image position at the top of that page aligned the same way the text is in this example, but have the text positioned at the bottom of the users screen. Also when they scroll both should be fixed so that it never disappears sort of like a fixed header.

Here is the very simple and plain [codepen](http://codepen.io/ericshio/pen/akaagd).

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" width="60px" />
    <ul>
        <li>Overview</li>
        <li>About</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}


img {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    float: right;
```

}

```
ul {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: So why not use fixed positioning...it seems to be what you are after?

Comment: I tried, but I couldn't get anything to work lol I have been at this for over 4 hours now. Maybe I am just being ridiculous lol and missing something super obvious.

Comment: & I am using fixed positioning for the div already.

Comment: You can use fixed positioning more than once..

Comment: Tried that as well, and it throws off the alignment of the logo, try it in a jsfiddle or codepen, I have tried on all and alle except div same result. Might as well just put it on div, same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position: fixed;` and `bottom: 0;` to your `ul` element.

Comment: This does get the text down to the bottom however the logo is no longer aligned with the right side of the text anymore.

Comment: Sorry for the edit, was just wondering what would happen lol.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code might help you:
html:

```
<div class="header">
    <span class="block">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" width="60px" />
    <br/>
        </span>
        <span class="block">
            <ul>
            <li>Overview</li>
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>
            </span>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.header {
    border: 0px solid green;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}
div.header.img {
    border: 5px solid green;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}

div.header.ul {
    bottom: 10%;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}

span.block {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, did not work for me. Could you post a jsfiddle/codepen with the working code? I even tweaked the html to fit your classes.